# Идентификатор полигона Yandex

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-maps-embed

Подскажите пожалуйста, как идентифицировать полигон. Строю в конструкторе карту с полигонами, потом экспортирую в geojson и у себя на сайте уже добавляю их из файла на карту яндекса. Только по описанию?

Answer (score 2):

У каждого объекта есть уникальный числовой id, начинающийся с нуля. Он инкрементируется и присваивается каждому новому объекту.

Либо в описании придумывать свой ключ

Comment: Т.е. вместо описания ключ какой-то? Если я удалил и добавил другую зону, id станет удаленного элемента или будет автоинкремент?

Comment: Рассчитается заново, id удаленного элемента займет добавленный после него объект и далее инкремент.
Да, вместо описания можешь придумать уникальный ключ и по нему уже идентифицировать